# Rails 3 - delete_all doesn't support limit scope whereas MySQL supports it

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table with 9 millions of records. I was periodically syncing this data to a third party. I am keeping a column that tells if a particular row has already been synced or not.

Now I need to delete almost `6 million` synced rows and I am not sure if running

```
Model.where(:sync_flag => true).delete_all
```

would be a nice idea. There are hundreds of inserts per second and I think it might result in locking the table in a way that would hurt/block the inserts ( MySQL expert needed here to correct )

With the above prologue, I thought of using a delete with a limit clause in a loop to delete all the records until none left but with the following

```
Model.where(:sync_flag => true).limit(5000).delete_all
```

it raised an exception `delete_all doesn't support limit scope`.

Is there a workaround to deal with the issue without leaving the Rails environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.send(:delete_sql,'delete from <table name> where sync_flag = true limit 1000')`

You have to use `send` because 'delete_sql' is protected, but this works.

Another solution might be

`Model.connection.exec_delete('DELETE FROM <table name> where sync_flag=true LIMIT 10000', 'DELETE', [])`

It'll return the affected rows AND also will log the query through the rails logger.

Answer (score 1):

How about executing a SQL command here?

```
Model.connection.exec_delete('DELETE FROM models WHERE sync_flag = 1 LIMIT 5000', 'DELETE', [])
```

Comment: MySQL threw this error when I tried your solution `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery`

Comment: It is Percona Server 5.6.25.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Model.where(:sync_flag => true).limit(5000).destroy_all
```

You can find more details at:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all

Comment: that would initiate 5000 delete queries. I used delete_all only to avoid it in the first place